# Only the first RelativeLayout is rendered in for loop

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to create several RelativeLayouts with two TextViews each, using "for" loop and insert those RelativeLayouts into LinearLayout, selected with id, using addView, but only the first RelativeLayout is rendered. Also I have a button in the layout after that LinearLayout. That button also is not rendered. Could you please help me in identifying a mistake in my code? Logcat does not show any error while rendering. Thank you.

MainFragment.java:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy, EEEE");
    Date date = new Date();
    String[] timeNames;

    public static MainFragment newInstance() {
        return new MainFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.date0);
        textView.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
        timeNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.time_names);

        LinearLayout parentToday = view.findViewById(R.id.today_times);
        RelativeLayout newRelativeLayout;
        TextView newTextView;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            newRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
            newRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            newTextView = new TextView(getContext());
            newTextView.setText(timeNames[i]);
            newTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            newRelativeLayout.addView(newTextView);
            newTextView = new TextView(getContext());
            newTextView.setText("00:00");
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            newTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
            newRelativeLayout.addView(newTextView);
            parentToday.addView(newRelativeLayout);
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/internet_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/internet_check"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/today_times"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Показать на неделю"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: All loops are iterated, I have checked with Toast.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The problem was in the following lines:

```
newTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

and

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

I had changed them to the following ones:

```
newTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

After that the problem was solved.